# Why isn't the action error message passed to the next page?

Tags: java, struts2

I am developing a login function which authenticate users from data stored in DB, when I tried to display the login error message on the next JSP to be displayed, the message wasn't shown even though the login info didn't match.

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

  <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="login" class="package1.LoginAction">
      <result name="success">MainPage.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**ApplicationResources.properties**

```
  label.username=User Name
  label.password=Password
  label.login=Login
  label.domain=Select Domain
  error.login=Invalid Username/Password. Please try again.
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<table border="0" align="center">
  <tr><s:actionerror /></tr>
</table>

<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
  <table border="0" align="center">
    <tr><s:textfield name="uid" key="label.username" size="20" /></tr>
    <tr><s:password name="psw" key="label.password" size="20" /></tr>
    <tr><s:select name="domain"
                  key="label.domain"
                  headerKey="1"
                  headerValue="-- Please Select --"
                  list="#{'01':'Tutor','02':'Student'}" /></tr>
    <tr><s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" /></tr>
  </table>
</s:form>
```

**LoginAction.java**

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
        conURL = "jdbc:informix-sqli://*********/fxg:INFORMIXSERVER=" +
                "sgdbuat11;user=*****;password=******";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String qstr = "SELECT * FROM tutor";
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(qstr);
    int count = 0;
    String msg = "";
    while (rset.next()) {
        String username = rset.getString("uid");
        if (this.uid.equals(username)) {
            count++;
            String password = rset.getString("psw1");
            if (this.psw.equals(password)) {
                msg = "success";
            } else {
                msg = "wrongpsw";
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return "error";
    } else if (msg == "wrongpsw") {
        return "error";
    } else {
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you log an exception then just continue on? Also, your return values are being selected based on comparing strings using `==`; it may work **in this case** because of string interning, but this is a *horrible* practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you use the key `error.login` so how do you expect struts to display it? You need to put the error message yourself, e.g. by calling `addActionError("your message here")` in your action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see where you have added the `addActionError`basically if you want to set any such Action level error all you need to do it to call addActionError() or ActionMessage once you set them than at your jsp page ypu need to show them using `<s:actionerror/>` or `<s:actionmessage/>`

yuo need to set something like in your action class

```
 if (count==0)
      {
             addActionError("Invalid Username/Password. Please try again");
             return "error" ;             
       }
     else if (msg=="wrongpsw"){
         addActionError("Invalid Username/Password. Please try again");    
        return "error";

     }
     else{
         return "success";
     }
```

additional its always better to check if there exist any error in the stack on your jsp

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
<table border="0" align="center">
            <tr><s:actionerror/></tr></table>
</s:if>
```

hope this will help